# CodeBlocks each time recompile the ofxUI headers

Tags: compilation, codeblocks, openframeworks

I am developing a relatively simple C++ project in Ubuntu, basing on [the OpenFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/) toolkit, including the addon [ofxUI](https://github.com/rezaali/ofxUI). I use the CodeBlocks as IDE.

Each time when I build the project, it seems that the CodeBlocks and the gcc recompile all ofxUI files, in spite of the fact that these files have not been changed.

There is the "build log":

```
-------------- Build: Debug in libopenFrameworks ---------------

Target is up to date.

-------------- Build: Debug in RoombotsInterface ---------------

Using makefile: Makefile
compiling x86_64 object for:  src/ApplicationGUI.cpp
In file included from /home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUI.h:170:0,
                 from src/main.h:58,
                 from src/Robot.h:10,
                 from src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:4:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIRadio.h: In member function ‘void ofxUIRadio::init(float, float, std::string, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, int)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIRadio.h:62:33: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIRadio.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUIRadio::setDrawPadding(bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIRadio.h:75:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIRadio.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUIRadio::setDrawPaddingOutline(bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIRadio.h:86:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIRadio.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUIRadio::setVisible(bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIRadio.h:102:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIRadio.h: In member function ‘void ofxUIRadio::activateToggle(std::string)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIRadio.h:110:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIRadio.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUIRadio::setParent(ofxUIWidget*)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIRadio.h:134:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
In file included from /home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUI.h:176:0,
                 from src/main.h:58,
                 from src/Robot.h:10,
                 from src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:4:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUIToggleMatrix::setDrawPadding(bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h:81:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUIToggleMatrix::setDrawPaddingOutline(bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h:92:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUIToggleMatrix::setVisible(bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h:108:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h: In member function ‘void ofxUIToggleMatrix::activateToggle(std::string)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h:118:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUIToggleMatrix::setParent(ofxUIWidget*)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h:140:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h: In member function ‘void ofxUIToggleMatrix::setAllToggles(bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h:162:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h: In member function ‘void ofxUIToggleMatrix::setAllTogglesAndTrigger(bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h:171:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h:177:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h: In member function ‘void ofxUIToggleMatrix::setToggle(int, int, bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIToggleMatrix.h:185:31: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
In file included from /home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUI.h:181:0,
                 from src/main.h:58,
                 from src/Robot.h:10,
                 from src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:4:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h: In member function ‘void ofxUIDropDownList::addToggle(std::string)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h:94:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
In file included from /home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUI.h:181:0,
                 from src/main.h:58,
                 from src/Robot.h:10,
                 from src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:4:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h: In member function ‘void ofxUIDropDownList::removeToggle(std::string)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h:123:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h:138:45: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h: In member function ‘void ofxUIDropDownList::initToggles(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&, int)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h:182:33: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUIDropDownList::setParent(ofxUIWidget*)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h:234:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUIDropDownList::setVisible(bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h:292:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h: In member function ‘void ofxUIDropDownList::setToggleVisibility(bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h:301:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUIDropDownList::triggerEvent(ofxUIWidget*)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h:335:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h: In member function ‘void ofxUIDropDownList::activateToggle(std::string)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIDropDownList.h:354:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
In file included from /home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUI.h:184:0,
                 from src/main.h:58,
                 from src/Robot.h:10,
                 from src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:4:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIMovingGraph.h: In member function ‘void ofxUIMovingGraph::addPoint(float)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIMovingGraph.h:101:30: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
In file included from /home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUI.h:187:0,
                 from src/main.h:58,
                 from src/Robot.h:10,
                 from src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:4:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In destructor ‘virtual ofxUICanvas::~ofxUICanvas()’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:44:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘void ofxUICanvas::saveSettings(std::string)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:146:50: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
In file included from /home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUI.h:187:0,
                 from src/main.h:58,
                 from src/Robot.h:10,
                 from src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:4:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUICanvas::update()’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:652:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUICanvas::mouseMoved(int, int)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:800:36: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUICanvas::mouseDragged(int, int, int)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:809:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUICanvas::mousePressed(int, int, int)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:819:36: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUICanvas::mouseReleased(int, int, int)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:828:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUICanvas::windowResized(int, int)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:841:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUICanvas::keyPressed(int)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:861:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUICanvas::keyReleased(int)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:869:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘ofxUIWidget* ofxUICanvas::getWidgetHit(float, float)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:891:45: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘void ofxUICanvas::autoSizeToFitWidgets()’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:952:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘void ofxUICanvas::centerWidgetsOnCanvas(bool, bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:989:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1020:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUICanvas::removeWidget(ofxUIWidget*)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1063:50: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
In file included from /home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUI.h:187:0,
                 from src/main.h:58,
                 from src/Robot.h:10,
                 from src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:4:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUICanvas::addWidget(ofxUIWidget*)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1191:36: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1238:36: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1258:36: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘ofxUIWidget* ofxUICanvas::addWidgetDown(ofxUIWidget*, ofxWidgetAlignment, bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1297:15: warning: enumeration value ‘OFX_UI_ALIGN_TOP’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1297:15: warning: enumeration value ‘OFX_UI_ALIGN_BOTTOM’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘ofxUIWidget* ofxUICanvas::addWidgetUp(ofxUIWidget*, ofxWidgetAlignment, bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1327:15: warning: enumeration value ‘OFX_UI_ALIGN_TOP’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1327:15: warning: enumeration value ‘OFX_UI_ALIGN_BOTTOM’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘void ofxUICanvas::setWidgetColor(int, ofColor)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1549:37: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1556:37: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1563:37: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1570:37: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1577:37: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1584:37: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1591:37: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘void ofxUICanvas::setDrawWidgetPadding(bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1619:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘void ofxUICanvas::setDrawWidgetPaddingOutline(bool)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1632:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h: In member function ‘std::vector<ofxUIWidget*> ofxUICanvas::getWidgetsOfType(ofxWidgetType)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUICanvas.h:1647:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
In file included from /home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUI.h:188:0,
                 from src/main.h:58,
                 from src/Robot.h:10,
                 from src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:4:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIScrollableCanvas.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUIScrollableCanvas::update()’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIScrollableCanvas.h:213:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIScrollableCanvas.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUIScrollableCanvas::mouseDragged(int, int, int)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIScrollableCanvas.h:267:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIScrollableCanvas.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUIScrollableCanvas::mousePressed(int, int, int)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIScrollableCanvas.h:299:45: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIScrollableCanvas.h: In member function ‘virtual void ofxUIScrollableCanvas::mouseReleased(int, int, int)’:
/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/src/ofxUIScrollableCanvas.h:321:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp: In function ‘PSOExperimentsParametersProxyAndDescription PSOExperimentsParametersProxy_06June2012_1(const Experiment&)’:
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:13:52: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:14:91: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:15:52: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:16:98: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:17:52: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:18:91: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:19:52: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:20:98: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:21:52: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:22:91: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:23:52: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:24:98: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:25:52: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:26:91: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:27:52: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:28:91: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:29:52: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:30:91: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:31:52: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:32:91: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:33:52: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:34:88: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:35:52: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:36:88: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:37:53: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:38:67: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
src/ApplicationGUI.h: In constructor ‘ApplicationGUI::ApplicationGUI()’:
src/ApplicationGUI.h:145:11: warning: ‘ApplicationGUI::robot’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
src/ApplicationGUI.h:48:10: warning:   ‘PSO* ApplicationGUI::d_pso’ [-Wreorder]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:41:1: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp: In member function ‘void ApplicationGUI::setGUI()’:
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:98:11: warning: unused variable ‘dim’ [-Wunused-variable]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp: In member function ‘void ApplicationGUI::drawSerial()’:
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:166:9: warning: unused variable ‘xOffset’ [-Wunused-variable]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:166:24: warning: unused variable ‘yOffset’ [-Wunused-variable]
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp: In member function ‘void ApplicationGUI::guiEvent(ofxUIEventArgs&)’:
src/ApplicationGUI.cpp:222:9: warning: unused variable ‘kind’ [-Wunused-variable]
find: `/home/user/of/addons/ofxUI/libs/*/lib/linux64': No such file or directory
find: `/home/user/of/addons/ofxXmlSettings/libs/*/lib/linux64': No such file or directory
find: `/home/user/of/addons/ofxKinect/libs/*/lib/linux64': No such file or directory
Package zlib was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `zlib.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'zlib' found
linking x86_64 bin/RoombotsInterface_debug linux64
/home/user/of/addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/lib/linux64/libopencv_core.a(system.o): In function `cv::tempfile(char const*)':
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv8tempfileEPKc+0x2f): warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
     compiling done
     to launch the application
     cd bin
     ./RoombotsInterface_debug
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 24 seconds)
0 errors, 95 warnings
```

I have tried to include ofxUI files to the CodeBlocks, but it does not benefit anyhow. I believe the solution for this problem should be very simple, it seems I do not understand something in the compilation process.

Thank you in advance for any advice, even very small!

I am developing a relatively simple C++ project in Ubuntu, basing on the OpenFrameworks toolkit, including the addon ofxUI. I use the CodeBlocks as IDE.

Each time when I build the project, it seems that the CodeBlocks and the gcc recompile all ofxUI files, in spite of the fact that these files have not been changed. In this case, it takes very much time to build the project every time even after a very tiny editing.

There is the "build log": http://pastebin.com/AMrRMAAY

I have tried to include ofxUI files to the CodeBlocks, but it does not benefit anyhow. I believe the solution for this problem should be very simple, it seems I do not understand something in the compilation process.

Thank you in advance for any advice, even very small!

(I have also asked this question on http://forum.openframeworks.cc/. If I will receive the answer there, I will immediately put the link here, and vice versa.)

Comment: I remember there was a bug in the Makefile template which causes this error. But can't find more information now. Please be patient, I'm sure someone will help you on the forums.

Comment: Thanks to arturo from the openFrameworks forum, he has supposed that the problem is that the whole ofxUI code is in header files, there are no "*.cpp" files. Have added the issue on the ofxUI github project web-site: https://github.com/rezaali/ofxUI/issues/56